# Finite sum & power series

Tags: power-series, direct-sum, negative-binomial

[image]

After some algebra, I found the whole expression equal to 10^9(1+ 2*(11/10) +3*(11/10)^2+...+10(11/10)^9)

The expression in inside the bracket is similar to power series of (1-x)^2. But, I don't know how to get a finite sum of n terms of (1-x)^2 series.

Need a hint. (Just need a hint, I know it's too easy)

Comment: Did  you observe a simple AGP

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Love wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

There is this simple and neat result for the sum of a special arithmetico-geometric sequence:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\,\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k = n(n+1)$$

This can be easily verified from the expression for the sum of a generic arithmetico-geometric sequence. What is surprising, at least for me, is that given the amount of powers of fractions in the sequence, the summation result is an integer! In other words:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k \, n^{n-k}\left(n+1\right)^k \equiv 0 \quad mod(n^n)$$

which I guess is by itself non trivial. Anyway, dividing your expression by $10^9$ gives exactly the above sequence with n=10 so the answer to your question is k=10$\cdot$11=110.
T. Hermsen